# NullPointerException in Keycloak when trying to get a token

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, access-token

I am trying to get a token from Keycloak 10.0.2 with the following request:

POST http://localhost:8051/auth/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token

x-www-form-urlencoded:

- grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange
- client_id: my-client
- client_secret: myClientSecret
- request_token_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token
- redirect_uri: http://localhost:8080/callback

I am getting the following error:

> 08:14:14,500 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-14) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.TokenManager.attachAuthenticationSession(TokenManager.java:425)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.exchangeClientToClient(TokenEndpoint.java:909)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.tokenExchange(TokenEndpoint.java:821)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:195)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor700.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:535)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:424)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:385)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:356)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:110)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
> at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:91)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
> at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The client is found and the secret is correct. If I misspell any of them I get a reasonable error, which points me directly to the issue.

Comment: What is the grant type you are using? authorization code/ implicit / password / client credentials? i guess u need authorization_code

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a token exchange, so you must specify the authorization token and the audience.

So, you must also provide the parameters below:

- audience: the target client id
- subject_token: the token to be exchanged

For example:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/claudio/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data client_id=confidential-app \
  --data client_secret=8a38ba25-8422-4fc3-960c-13eac4055e5b \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange" \
  --data subject_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ0X25udzFWNktCbHhGWFhnaGNhOURmUUlHUnJEYjNHUHc3RGhFZjhkX2lzIn0.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.ZqYu_KKX65-A5sn5uIsgBrt2WMabceI-Od67wZF1zxraNw7ADIDf9-K0iVb_rsWPaVnsDPfj82MKlhUOn2gQa5HNNukMNZ1K8UbdxkCM2bSymIHr8qXikl-31SD2VrQ2iZsA2_HoXb30TaRA7kZfJBO44rQI56kbqUUnquIEUd0K3GB6RNeBiZJN08xX9SUaqJy4m_0GgwYs59HvpGLJTMc0ipAjpG4IljlstM2oci6gnGF9Ld79y-FvUHLuhj-bFLC2jkRYuSyrhisr9eSqinfknxy-AW6ZQo-fVM3dSRVuj18fBVu25Gc5_dMgwuHJZNpUowWKAyqLD7EWPl26LQ \
  --data audience=public_app
```